# xib convert to programmatically view

Tags: swift, dynamic

I need to use custom views instead of views created with xib file.

How do I convert and use nib/xib file to programmatically view ?

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    var item: ViewModelItem? {
        didSet {
            titleLabel?.text = item?.title
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        selectionStyle = .none
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel?

    static var nib:UINib {
        return UINib(nibName: identifier, bundle: nil)
    }

    static var identifier: String {
        return String(describing: self)
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        accessoryType = selected ? .checkmark : .none
    }
}
```

I added it instead of xib.  How should i send this?

I want the xib file to be programmatically added and controllable.
I want the xib file to be programmatically added and controllable.

```
class CustomCellView: UIView {

    convenience init(frame: CGRect,checkboxTag:Int?) {
        self.init(frame: frame)
        self.addCustomView(checkboxTag: checkboxTag)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func addCustomView(checkboxTag : Int?) {       
        var checkbox: UIButton = ClickingCheckbox()
        if((checkboxTag) != nil)
        {
            checkbox.tag = checkboxTag!
        }
        self.addSubview(checkbox)
    } 
}
class ClickingCheckbox: UIButton {
    convenience init() {
        self.init(frame:  CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
        self.setImage(UIImage(named: "unfilled.png"), for: UIControlState.selected)
        self.setImage(UIImage(named: "filled.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc private func buttonTapped() {
        self.isSelected = !self.isSelected
    }
}
```

Comment: Explain the problem statement clearly.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using view from Nib, it calls `AwakeFromNib()` method, custom views from code are using Init() methods.
To convert you Xib to programmatically code you need to setup all UI inside `Init()` method and move all initialConfiguration methods from `AwakeFromNib()` to `Init()`

Comment: I don't fully understand, may I ask for a simple code example?